# Devise authentication logs in after password change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, logout, password-recovery

Devise authentication gem in Rails.

How to prevent automatic logging in after password change by "forgot password" link?

Ideally it would be nice to display the page with message "New password has been saved".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to override Devise's `passwords_controller` which you can see the default methods for [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb). First, create your own controller which will inherit from the Devise controller:

`class User::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController`

Once you have your controller ready, add in all of the other methods that you do not want to override, and simply call super inside of them. This will be the `new`, `edit`, and `create` methods. Also don't forget to add the protected `after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)` method.

The method that you are concerned with overriding is the `update` action.

```
def update
  self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)

  if resource.errors.empty?
    flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
    set_flash_message(:notice, "Your flash message here")
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  else
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

All we change here is to remove the line to sign in the user with a redirect to the sign in page, and then set our custom flash message.

Lastly, you have to tell devise to use your new controller, so in `routes.rb` change `devise_for :users` to:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => 'users/passwords' }
```

And that should do it.

Answer (score 3):

As of Devise [3.5.0](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/f0992e4a96352dbb2dfec731f46a51f99a013b29), this behaviour can be controlled with a setting, which can be found in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```rb
# When set to false, does not sign a user in automatically after their password is
# reset. Defaults to true, so a user is signed in automatically after a reset.
config.sign_in_after_reset_password = false
```

The flash message shown will be `Your password has been changed successfully.`, but can be adjusted in `config/locales/devise.en.yml`:

```
en:
  devise:
    passwords:
      updated_not_active: New password has been saved
```

Comment: What if I´m using a custom UsersController? I've changed this behavior in `devise.rb` but nothing changes, also the `sign_in current_user, bypass:true` doesn't work either.

Comment: Depends on what your Controller looks like. Does it inherit from some Devise-Controller? Are you calling `super`? If not, you must implement the logic yourself. Have a look at the [passwords controller](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/45b831c4ea5a35914037bd27fe88b76d7b3683a4/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L39), where the setting is used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an update based on 3.1.1 of devise

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

 def new
   super
 end

 def edit
   super
 end

 def create
   super
 end

 #override this so user isn't signed in after resetting password
 def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)

    if resource.errors.empty?
      resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
      flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
      set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_navigational_format?

      respond_with resource, :location => after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    else
      respond_with resource
    end

  end

protected

   def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
     new_session_path(resource)
   end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

The above said answer is correct but the thing is it varies according to the devise version. I followed the above said and i could not get it working and after some time i found that i am using devise version which does not support resource_params method, then i tried different for that version and got it working.